# C++ A nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object

Tags: c++, non-static

```
Vector2D tankPos = Tank_b017191c::GetTankPosition();
```

I am trying to call a function from a different class but I am getting this error:

> 47    IntelliSense: a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a
>   specific
>   object    e:\Repos\GameAI\GameAI\PathFinder_b017191c.cpp  113 21  GameAI

I have included Tank_b017191c.h in my header file but not getting very far..

Comment: You need an object to call a non-static member function.  `Object a; a.foo();`

Comment: you need an instance of that class, not just its type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that member function `GetTankPosition` is a non-static member function. You have to call it with using an instance of the class as for example

```
Tank_b017191c tank;
Vector2D tankPos  = tank.GetTankPosition();
```

or

```
Tank_b017191c tank( /* some arguments */ );
Vector2D tankPos  = tank.GetTankPosition();
```

Comment: I tried this but then I get 'Error: no default constructor exists for class "Tank_b017191c"

Comment: you are asking for the position of a `tank` . which one? have you created a `tank` to take the position of? if so, that's the variable you use.

Comment: @BR3TON It is just an example. You have to call the constructor (with parameters) that is defined in your class.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have something like this:

```
Tank_b017191c tank; // you first need to create an object of this class
Vector2D tankPos = tank.GetTankPosition();
```

Comment: I tried this but then I get 'Error: no default constructor exists for class "Tank_b017191c"

Comment: This means your Tank_b017191c class has no default constructor and you have defined your own constructors. So you will now have to initialize that object with whatever constructor you would use to initialize an object of that class.